# Why does the creation of a pluggable database in Oracle XE 21c fail with ORA-65100: "missing or invalid path prefix"?

Tags: database, windows, oracle, oracle-xe, oracle21c

I need to set up a new Oracle XE database after the server holding our old XE testing database suddenly died.
To do this I do have a .dmp file from when the database was functional.
The server is a Windows machine.
The database structure was originally created in an Oracle 11g environment but the server had been updated since so the .dmp was created in a 19c environment.
The new Oracle XE database I'm trying to set up is 21c.

The installation of Oracle XE worked, but trying to create a PDB fails with ORA-65100 "missing or invalid path prefix".
Issued the following statements in sqlplus via command line:

```sql
create pluggable database DATABASE_MAIN 
    admin user USERNAME identified by PASSWORD 
    storage (maxsize 2G) 
    default tablespace TS_DATA 
    datafile '/disk1/Oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN/DATABASE_MAIN.dbf' size 250M autoextend on 
    path_prefix = '/disk1/Oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN/' 
    file_name_convert = ('/disk1/Oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/pdbs/pdbseed', '/disk1/Oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN/');
```

So this line is currently throwing the error:

```sql
path_prefix = '/disk1/Oracle/product/21c/dbhomeXE/pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN/'
```

Things I've tried to get around the error:

- ran cmd as administrator in case its a simple permission issue
- created the missing folders myself ( /pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN )
- replaced /disk1 with /diskc to see if it makes a difference
- omitted /disk1 and started the string with /Oracle
- tried a different path ( /disk1/Oracle/product/21c/pdbs/DATABASE_MAIN/ )
- removed the trailing '/' at the end of the path prefix

Searching online for what invalidates the path prefix sadly didn't give me any answers however Oracle's documentation states the following as a valid example path prefix:

```sql
PATH_PREFIX = '/disk1/oracle/dbs/salespdb/'
```

This is my first time interacting with this "new" Oracle database structure of CDB/PDB as I've only worked with older databases so far that were built with the user/schema structure.

Comment: Why are you using Unix-style paths (with forward slashes) rather than Windows-style paths - is that valid? What is the actual full path to wherever you created the missing folders yourself?

Comment: Mostly out of habit. Also the entire Oracle documentation uses forward slashes. For completion's sake I issued the same command with backwards slashes and it showed the same error response. The full paths where I created the folders are C:\Oracle\product\21c\dbhomeXE\ **pdbs\DATABASE_MAIN** and C:\Oracle\product\21c\ **pdbs\DATABASE_MAIN** . Created directories emphasized. @AlexPoole

Comment: OK so your command actually now has `path_prefix = 'C:\Oracle\product\21c\dbhomeXE\pdbs\DATABASE_MAIN\'` rather than what you showed in the question?

Comment: I noticed I had a typo in that test so I re-did it, and it worked! So the issue was in fact the Unix style path in the string literal. A bit embarrassing that I didn't notice this myself. Would you like to write your clarification as a short answer so I can accept it? @AlexPoole

Comment: The whole question is off-topic for this site really so I imagine it'll be closed at some point, and as it's bordering on a typo (which is another close reason!), I'm not sure it would be helpful to anyone else. Glad you figured it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the issue was due to the UNIX style paths rather than Windows styled.

So changing the paths from

```
/disk1/foo/bar
```

to

```
C:\foo\bar
```

resolved the issue.

Here's the functional create-statement as run in sqlplus:

```sql
create pluggable database DATABASE_MAIN
    admin user USERNAME identified by PASSWORD
    storage (maxsize 2G)
    default tablespace TS_DATA
    datafile 'C:\Oracle\product\21c\oradata\XE\DATABASE_MAIN\DATABASE_MAIN.dbf' size 250M autoextend on
    path_prefix = 'C:\Oracle\product\21c\oradata\XE\DATABASE_MAIN'
    file_name_convert = ('C:\Oracle\product\21c\oradata\XE\pdbseed','C:\Oracle\product\21c\oradata\XE\DATABASE_MAIN');
```